# Problem downloading from Protonmail webui

Tags: epiphany, download

When I try to download an attachment using the Protonmail webui, I am met with the following:

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Perhaps you can try using Firefox. I also use ProtonMail and can download attachments just fine.

Comment: I can, but I want to use Epiphany and am trying to assist by filing bugs and features requests as that's about all I can do to assist outside of financial contributions.